# Selenium webdriver - How to select dynamic ID's using xpath?

Tags: html, xpath, selenium

Using xpath,I need to select text "level38a" using dynamic id "select" link. In HTML code i see  containing 2 `<td>` with text `"level38a"` and `"select"`.

PS : In my application i have more than 30 "select" link for different text. So using the `id="lnk_LEVEL_2449"` is not efficient.

I'm using the below code to select the text, but it's not clicking the select button.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td//a[@value='Select']]/td/a[contains(text(),'level38a')]"));`
```

HTML snippet

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <img class="imHeader" alt="" src="include/img/context/level_dash.gif">
        <img class="imHeader" alt="" src="include/img/context/icon_telco_level.gif">
        level38a
    </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>
        <a id="lnk_LEVEL_2449" href="jfn?isLevel=true&level=L4%3A2449&mfunc=614&cfunc=615&oid=L4%3A2191&ctx=L&jfnRC=9">Select</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This method
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td//a[@value='Select']]/td/a[contains(text(),'level38a')]"));` only finds the element, doesn't click it.
You have to add click() action. Like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td//a[@value='Select']]/td/a[contains(text(),'level38a')]")).click();
```

Edit:
I haven't looked at your xpath. It is wrong.
Please try these:

```
"//tr[td//a[contains(text(), 'Select')]]/td[contains(text(),'level38a')]"
```

or just:

```
"//td[contains(text(), 'level38a')]"
```

Comment: It din't work. Getting the following error,
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tr[td//a[@value='Select']]/td/a[contains(text(),'ShapeCSR')]"}

Comment: Would that be because it was "ShapeCSR", and not "level38a"?

Comment: @MrTi: It doen't matter. becuase i have different text like ShapeCSR, level38a etc... In the main code i'm passing the text as string,
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td//a[contains(text(), 'Select')]]/td[contains(text(),'"+ weeklyLevelName +"')]"));

Comment: @Robert: I tried with xpath you suggested("//tr[td//a[contains(text(), 'Select')]]/td[contains(text(),'level38a')]"). Able to locate the text on page. Once the text is located i need to click "Select" link, but it's not happening. I tried with adding click() at the end, but it doesn't help me.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Used the below xpath to select dynamic ID's and it worked fine. First it locate the text "level38a" in the page and click on "Select" link.

**driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),'level38a')]]/td//a[contains(text(),   'Select')]")).click();**